# Stuck on logo during Android-x86 boot on PC using removable disk

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, android-x86, android-pc

I'm trying to install Android-x86 on the POS desktop using USB.

I am done with the installation, but after rebooting it stuck on the logo.

Comment: Have you checked if your hardware is compatible before installing?